# how to filter records on count(of specific column value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

i have a table with columns

```
SponsorID  AccountID  CountryID
 123        456        236
 123        789        236
 123        654        40
 123        897        236
 123        978        40
 123        564        40
  '          '         '
  '          '         '
  '          '         '
```

I want to write a sql query to find the sponsorID's who have count of accountIDs having countryID = 40 more than 10 [ count(CountryID = 40) > 10 ]

Comment: can you please post your code what you tried so far ?

Comment: are you using all the 3 _versions_ of `sql` at the same time ??

Comment: I think you should try something like `SELECT SponsorID FROM TableName
WHERE CountryID = 40
GROUP BY SponsorID
HAVING COUNT(CountryID) > 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
Create 2 table (`TEMP` or `CTE`).
1)SponsorID , count(AccountID)>0
2)SponsorID  ,count(CountryID)>10 where CountryID=40
now join them.
```

Comment: @user1140237. here is where i am right now. SELECT TOP 1 SponsorID FROM (
SELECT et.sponsorID,COUNT(et.AccountID) AS downlinecount FROM commissions.[calcs].[vwEnrollerTreePermutated] et
INNER JOIN Commissions.[RFO].[synvw_GetAccount_Reporting] gar ON et.AccountID = gar.AccountID
 WHERE PeriodID = (SELECT MAX(PeriodID) FROM commissions.Reference.Periods WHERE ClosedDate IS NOT null) 
 GROUP BY et.SponsorID
HAVING COUNT(et.AccountID) BETWEEN 1350 AND 1500 AND COUNT(gar.countryID) > 2 ) a 
ORDER BY NEWID(). cant figure out how to get the count of the AccountID who are having CountryID = 40.